# how to remove nodes in an xml that is inside another xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml as an value of an element inside a Main xml.  I want to scrub off or delete a node within the inner xml.  How do I achieve that ?

For removing a node in main xml I am doing

```
var result = doc.Descendants("node1").Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "002");
 if (result != null)
                    {
                        result.Remove();
                    }
```

Here is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
    <node1>id="001" version="1.0"</node1>
    <node2>id="002" version="1.0"</node1>
    <report>raw = "<response = "10"><innerxml><prod>date = "18082016" name="pqr"</prod><seg1>id="002" name = "sqs"</seg1></innerxml></response>"</report>
</root>
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid. **"** is not allowed in node values.

Comment: the value of element raw is another xml. Thats how I receive them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but your xml is not. the XML should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
    <node1 id="001" version="1.0"></node1>
    <node2 id="002" version="1.0"></node2>
</root>
```

Comment: the value of element raw is another xml .. From "<response> ---xml---  </response>"