# How to replace the attribute value in xml when the attribute name remains same but value of it changes in different nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have a xml and want to replace the attribute value everywhere I find it , the element name and attribute name remains the same but the attribute value to replace depends on its current value.

**original xml:**

```
<Loan>
<status="First">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My name is abc and I am a doctor"/>
</status>
<status="Second">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My name is def and I am an actor"/>  
</status>
<status="Third">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My name is xyz and I am a coder"/>
</status>
</Loan>
```

**Want the output to be:**

```
<Loan>
<status="First">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My  doctor"/>
</status>
<status="Second">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My  actor"/> 
</status>
<status="Third">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My  coder"/>
</status>
</Loan>
```

I am doing some operation to extract the part of raw_xml and replace its current value.

I have the code how to extract and replace the value.

but as I am using the method Single/Default it is failing with an error

> Sequence contains more than one matching element

How to get pass through it and loop through each of it and replace the value using Xdocument.descendants .. I dont want to use Xpath as the real xml I'm dealing has so many inner nodes in it and getting xpath for each attribute is really tough.

**Current code I am using for replacing.**

```
foreach (var report in doc.Descendants("report"))
{
    var xms = "";

    xms = report.Attribute("raw_xml").Value;

    //My code to change to extract the required attribute value goes here..creating an xmsdoc variable and storing the output value for attribute in it

    var element = doc.Descendants("report").Single(x => x.Attribute("active").Value == "True");
    element.SetAttributeValue("raw_xml", xmsdoc.ToString());
}
```

Comment: xml is case sensitive so change from "Report" to "report" in descendants.

Comment: oops , yeah its actually report .. I mistyped here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok im create a compilable example:

`test.xml` (with attribute-fixes named as `id`)

```
<Loan>
  <status id="First">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My name is abc and I am a doctor"/>
  </status>
  <status id="Second">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My name is def and I am an actor"/>
  </status>
  <status id="Third">
    <report active = "True" raw_xml = "My name is xyz and I am a coder"/>
  </status>
</Loan>
```

Program.cs

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication99
{
  class Program
  {
    static string FixXmlString(string value)
    {
      int namePos = value.IndexOf(" name ");
      if (namePos < 0) return value; // name not found
      int lastSpace = value.LastIndexOf(' ');

      int cutLength = lastSpace - namePos;

      return value.Remove(namePos, cutLength);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
      XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

      foreach (XElement x in doc.Descendants("report").Where(x => x.Attribute("active").Value == "True"))
      {
        var attribute = x.Attribute("raw_xml");

        if (attribute != null)
        {
          attribute.Value = FixXmlString(attribute.Value);
        }
      }

      doc.Save("new.xml");
    }

  }
}
```

result in `new.xml`:

```
<Loan>
  <status id="First">
    <report active="True" raw_xml="My doctor" />
  </status>
  <status id="Second">
    <report active="True" raw_xml="My actor" />
  </status>
  <status id="Third">
    <report active="True" raw_xml="My coder" />
  </status>
</Loan>
```

Edit: add missing "active" check

Comment: The idea has worked for me in implementing my real xml. But setting the attribute value to a string type there is an increase in the size of my xml from 300 kb to 1254 kb . Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: No issues, Wonderful !! Used this idea to solve my other issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960338/how-to-remove-nodes-in-an-xml-that-is-inside-another-xml